# How to apply different loaders depending on entry?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a Webpack configuration with 2 entries:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    public: './src/public.js',
    admin: './src/adminPanel.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                targets: {
                  browsers: ['last 5 years']
                }
              }]
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

It produces 2 files: a script for the public pages and a script for the admin panel. The entries import another JS files including some shared files. I need the public script to support many browsers and the admin panel script to support only the latest Chrome.

I want to achieve it by using different `browsers` setting depending on the entry so that if a JS file is used in the public entry, it is loaded with one settings, and if a file is used in the admin entry, it is loaded with the other settings. How to do it in Webpack 4?

I know I can solve my problem by [exporting 2 Webpack configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types#exporting-multiple-configurations) but I wonder how to use different loaders or adjust a loader options basing on the entry file.

Comment: Do you need to apply different loaders only on the entry files, or to files that are children of children... of each entry?

Comment: @alex-rokabilis The second option: the entry file and all its dependencies

Comment: Why not use two webpack config files, one per entry?

Comment: @pintxo Because it's a constraint of the question. Of cause I can use individual config for each entry.

Answer (score 3):

> I need the public script to support many browsers and the admin panel script to support only the latest Chrome. I want to achieve it by using different browsers setting depending on the entry.

`babel` supports multiple configurations per directory (recursively up to it finds a `babel` configuration file up to a `package.json` is found:

> Babel loads .babelrc (and .babelrc.js / package.json#babel) files by
>   searching up the directory structure starting from the "filename"
>   being compiled (limited by the caveats below). This can be powerful
>   because it allows you to create independent configurations for
>   subsections of a package.
>   Source: [`babel` docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration.)

Currently you have placed your `babel` configuration in your webpack configuration which is applied project wide. What you could do is remove the `babel` config from your webpack, place your `adminPanel.js` and `public.js` in separate directories with each their own `.babelrc` (or other babel config) file which have different targets for `@babel/presets-env`.

```
.
├── src
|   ├── admin
|   |   ├── adminPanel.js
|   |   ├── .babelrc
|   |
|   ├── public
|   |   ├── public.js
|   |   ├── .babelrc
|
├── package.json
```

Your `./src/admin/.babelrc` could look like:

```js
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": "chrome 70"
    }]]
}
```

And your `./src/public/.babelrc`:

```js
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": "last 5 years"
    }]]
}
```

I've just tried this with the following code in both `./src/admin/adminPanel.js` and `./src/public/public.js`

```js
[1, 2, 3].map(num => `number ${num}`)

let [x, y, z] = [2, 4, 6]
```

Which `webpack` and `babel` have transformed to

```js
// ./dist/admin.js
[1, 2, 3].map(num => `number ${num}`);
let [x, y, z] = [2, 4, 6];
```

and

```js
// ./dist/public.js
[1, 2, 3].map(function (num) {
  return "number ".concat(num);
});
var x = 2,
    y = 4,
    z = 6;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I have the public and the admin files in separate directories, I would be able to solve my problem adding a simple `include` parameter to the rule or using a function as the `use` value. The feature is that I have some files that are shared and must be loaded differently based on the entry file.